# Trying to follow a sample and I can't figure out why there are errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to follow a sample and I can't figure out why there are errors. Any help...it's probably a formatting thing:

```
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';
// Express app setup
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
server.on('listening', () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on port: 3000');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.end('Hello Express');
  });};
```

My two error messages are:

1. Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

   9 |   app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   10 |     res.end('Hello Express');

   > 11 |   });};
   >    |       ^
2. ')' expected.

Comment: You forgot `)` before `;` at the last line.

Comment: I put that in:import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';
// Express app setup
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
server.on('listening', () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on port: 3000');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.end('Hello Express');
  });});

Comment: Now it gives me 14 errors...something about: Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'. (linebreak-style)

Comment: First of all - please, use markdown to paste code. That's not a error - it's a messages from ESLint.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is markdown

Comment: Also it says, "Unexpected console statement. (no-console)"

Comment: You can read about comment formating [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) or by clicking "help" button under "Add Comment".

Comment: if you want disable these messages, you're able to [configure your ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)

Comment: What does " Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'. (linebreak-style)"mean?

Comment: @dn18... what ya.ymer was trying to say is that, enclose any code you're trying to share in "{}"... this way its easier to understand by others. the rmarkdown he was referring to is a way to format your questions to look nicer for others to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a few issues here:

1. The `import` syntax is not valid in nodejs unless you have a transpiler to intercept it.
2. Your setup with express is just wrong. You’re defining your route handlers after you’ve started the server.

Here’s what you want - with valid common js syntax

```
const http = require('http')
const app = require('express')()

app.get('*', (req, res) => res.send(' Hello Express'))

const server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is listening on port: 3000'))
```

Comment: @TheIncorrigble1
Thanks for the updates. I was doing this on a phone. However the last 2 lines are now incorrect. You're attaching an event handler after the event is already fired. The previous syntax was valid for logging after the server started. Will re-edit

Comment: I thought something looked off about that part.  I didn't change your code besides reducing it some with the app initialization.

Comment: Ah yeah you’re right. The curse of copy paste. Thanks again.